# Can we identify the date on which someone liked my page?

Tags: php, facebook-like

How can we identity the date on which someone liked my page.

is there any way where we can identify **the date** on which someone **liked my page** ?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't even get a list of people that like your page, so you can't get a date they liked it.  The only information you can get is how many people like it.

You can view a chart of how many people liked your page over time at [Facebook Insights](http://www.facebook.com/insights).

Answer (score 0):

Well no, You can make a graph call to the statuses and feeds of a user with valid access_token to get the id and name of the people who liked the post.. The timestamp can be found for the comments though ..

```
 {
         "id": "257821xxxxxxx",
         "from": {
            "name": "Maxxxxxx",
            "id": "100xxxxxx"
         },
         "message": "incredible ..",
         "updated_time": "2011-09-15T11:21:15+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "6xxxxxx6",
                  "name": "Axxxxxxxxxa"
               }
            ]
         },
         "comments": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "257xxxxxxxxxxxx904",
                  "from": {
                     "name": "Maxxxxxxxxxxal",
                     "id": "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                  },
                  "message": "htxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "can_remove": true,
                  "created_time": "2011-09-15T11:22:06+0000"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
```

Comment: if user only click on like then there will be no timestamp, right ?